# Unity ui object cannot align if its parent is VerticalLayoutGroup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

see my gif
[image]

if parent object has component "VerticalLayoutGroup", the child object's > RectTransform > Anchors is grey, can I cannot change it, **is there way to unfreeze this child Anchors in script?**

"Vertical Layout Group" > "Child Alignment" cannot fit my need, in some case, I only wanna align specific child, for ex, in gif, I only wanna align first red child to center

Answer (score 0):

The VerticalLayoutGroup takes over the placement of its children, so you cannot make changes to the position.  The "Child Alignment" tells the VerticalLayoutGroup how to align the children.  In your case you are telling the VerticalLayoutGroup to align its children according to the "Upper Left".  So, your scene appears to be working as expected and is as described in the Unity3D documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html.

If you want to have a custom behavior (such as "Align Only Red Images") you'll have to create your own script (attached to the same parent, instead of the VerticalLayoutGroup) that would inspect its children before aligning them.